# Есть скомпилированный проект QT 5.13.2 в QCreator, как упаковать его в deb?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt5, deb

Проект QT 5.13.2 собран в QCreator на Ubuntu 18.4

Вопрос в том как подтянуть к нему библиотеки и собрать deb пакет.

Чтение гайдов на Хабре не прояснили ситуацию.

Может кто работал с debild и dh_make или debhelper и может рассказать или дать ссылку на ресурс, где понятно что для чего делать?

Comment: если проект перевести на cmake, то cpack, если нет то сделай через dpkg buildpackage -  debian/rules порстой довольно

Comment: Спасибо, тебе. Попробую dpkg buildpackage - debian/rules.